# Labelling a rubber band (QgsRubberBand)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, annotation, qgsrubberband

It is possible to label `QgsRubberBand` or `QgsVertexMarker` with a text annotation (`QgsTextAnnotationItem`).

See this MWE:

```
...
r_polyline = QgsRubberBand(iface.mapCanvas(), False)
r_polyline.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points), None)
r_polyline.setWidth(2)
r_polyline.setColor(QColor(0,255,0,255))
seg = QgsFeature()
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points))
length = seg.geometry().length()
self.distance_list.append(length)
symbol = QgsMarkerSymbolV2()
symbol.setSize(0)
lbltext = QTextDocument(str(round(length,2)) + ' m')
label = QgsTextAnnotationItem(iface.mapCanvas())
label.setMapPosition(seg.geometry().interpolate(length/2.0).asPoint())
label.setDocument(lbltext)
label.setFrameSize(QSizeF(lbltext.size().width(),lbltext.size().height()))
label.setFrameBorderWidth(0)
label.setFrameColor(QColor("#ffffff"))
label.setFrameBackgroundColor(QColor("#ffffff"))
label.setMarkerSymbol(symbol)
...
```

In the moment it looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to label a rubber band (or edit the text annotations) like in this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The recent addition of the [annotations feature](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog322/index.html#feature-new-point-text-tool) in QGIS 3.22 allows to place labels anywhere on the map canvas. Most importantly it allows placing labels at an angle which doesn't seem possible with the older `QgsTextAnnotation`. With a bit of effort this can be used to label a rubber band geometry.

The underlying API changes had already been implemented since QGIS 3.16, meaning the example script below can be used on version 3.16 and upwards.

```py
# define some test data LineString
pt1 = QgsPoint(12.354931, 56.761697)
pt2 = QgsPoint(12.468290, 56.124512)
line = QgsLineString(pt1, pt2)
line_geom = QgsGeometry(line)

# calculate length of line
d = QgsDistanceArea()
d.setEllipsoid('WGS84')
length = d.measureLength(line_geom)

# calculate gradient of line to place label at an angle
gradient = QgsGeometryUtils.gradient(pt1, pt2)
# some math to convert gradient to an angle in degrees
angle = math.degrees(math.atan(gradient))

# calculate point along line with offset 
# to place label beneath line and not directly on top
# (since QGIS 3.20 use QgsGeometryUtils.perpendicularOffsetPointAlongSegment() instead)
# https://qgis.org/api/classQgsGeometryUtils.html#a84f1836941047aff664e7b913c051ae0
mX = pt1.x() + ( pt2.x() - pt1.x() ) * 0.5
mY = pt1.y() + ( pt2.y() - pt1.y() ) * 0.5
pX = pt1.x() - pt2.x()
pY = pt1.y() - pt2.y()
normalX = -pY
normalY = pX
normalLength = math.sqrt(( normalX * normalX ) + ( normalY * normalY ))
normalX /= normalLength
normalY /= normalLength
x = mX - 0.001 * normalX
y = mY - 0.001 * normalY

# add annotation label
annotation_layer = QgsProject.instance().mainAnnotationLayer()
label = QgsAnnotationPointTextItem(str(round(length,2)) + ' m', QgsPointXY(x, y))
label.setAngle(angle)
annotation_layer.addItem(label)

# display geometry as rubber band
r = QgsRubberBand(iface.mapCanvas(), QgsWkbTypes.LineGeometry)
r.setWidth(2)
r.setColor(QColor(0,255,0,255))
r.setToGeometry(line_geom, None)

iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

[image: label]